# Cocoa - Create multiple instance of my application

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstask, nspipe

My requirement is to create multiple instance of my application.
I am able to create multiple instance without argument successfully but as I am passing some argument with my runCommand, it creates infinite instances of my application and to stop this I have to shutdown my System forcefully.

Thanks in advance :

my working code is below :

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename
{
    isOpenFileFlag = YES;

    NSString *filePathStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"open -n /Applications/MyApp.app --args %@",filename];

    [self runCommand:filePathStr];

    return YES;
}

- (NSString *) runCommand: (NSString *) commandToRun {
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c" , [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun], nil];
    NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *output;
    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return output;

}
```

**Only thing that I have to do is to create multiple instance of my application one by one.**

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are creating a loop, because every instance that launches, launches another instance and so on..
You have to stop creating instances, when you have enough of them. (Captain Obvious)

I guess there are multiple ways of doing this. You could check how many instances of your app are running at the moment.

Another approach (what I would do): Create a `NSNumber` object at first launch that you can write to `NSPasteBoard`. Every other instance loads the number and adds one to it. If you have the right count, stop the loop.